# Setting setNeedsDisplay on another view

Tags: ios, view

I have a controller for a "settings view" in where the user changes some of the properties of what's drawn in my MyView view. But, I can't figure out how to call setNeedsDisplay on MyView instead of my SettingsView.

MyView is an UIView, and it has its own controller called MyViewController.

Inside this view, I'm drawing rectangles of a kind, and with different colors. In SettingsViewController I change a parameter which affects what kind of rectangles are drawn in MyView. However, for that to happen, the user has to (they're on different tabs) switch views, and perform some action so that setNeedsDisplay gets called. I'm trying to call setNeedsDisplay FROM SettingsViewController, but I can't do self.view setNeedsDisplay beacause it'll call setNeedsDisplay on MyView. Does this make more sense?

Comment: You need to notify MyView somehow of the change of property and then you can call setNeedsDisplay on MyView.

Comment: @rocky is it not possible to call setNeedsDisplay on MyView from another controller?

Comment: It is hard to figure out what the problem is. You have a settings view. Ok. What is MyView? Is it a UIView subclass or a UIViewController subcalss? Is it a subview of your settings view? How is it created?

Comment: If the controller owns the view, yes.

Comment: @SimonGoldeen added more details and hopefully it'll convey my issue more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view that you want to redraw. So if you're in `SettingsViewController` you need a handle to `MyViewController`. You mentioned you're in a `TabBarController`, so you could access the view through this. Eg (assuming MyViewController is the first tab and you're in SettingsViewController in another tab):

`[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0] view] setNeedsDisplay]`

Comment: As David mentions below, it's probably a better idea for the `SettingsViewController` to 'announce' that a setting was changed, so that interested view controllers can respond as necessary, rather than directly refreshing the view from settings. This keeps your controllers independent of one another. Notifications are one way to go (usually best when there are multiple interested objects), delegates another (usually when there is only one interested object).

Answer (score 2):

A better question to ask would be "How can I design this so that my view controllers are self-contained and not dependent on the hierarchy of other view controllers?"

It seems like the best solution in your case might be to use notifications to let your drawing view controller know that it needs to refresh because settings have changed.

In your settings view controller.h add:

```
#define kSettingsChangedNotification @"SettingsChangedNotification"
```

In your Settings view controller, when settings have been updated you can use:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kSettingsChangedNotification
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:nil];
```

And then in your drawing view controller add the following to your viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(onSettingsChanged:)
                                             name:kSettingsChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And, finally define onSettingsChanged in your drawing view controller:

```
-(void)onSettingsChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```